# jQuery: Check if all images have been loaded

Tags: jquery, image, load

Good morning!

I'm looking for a function which detects if all images are loaded. There are a few snippets on the internet with `$("img").load(function(){...})` but I read that `.load()` was deprecated in jQ 1.8 . If not, it doesn't seem to work for me though :D

I'm currently developing in jQ 2.1.4 and using TYPO3 7.4, so the easiest way for me would be a custom jQ function which you can apply on all images. Thats why I didn't even try out the snippets where you add the src-attribute afterwards. Don't want to mess around in my TypoScript if not 100%ly necessary.

Thanks,
Norman

Comment: use `$(window).load(function(){...})`

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali this is deprecated, better is to not use this shorthand but relevant method to bind event: `$(window).on('load', handler);`

Comment: well.... that was easy. Thanks alot!

Comment: I think .load was deprecated since it had the same name as the other .load ajax function. .on("load") is likely still with us

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice

Comment: `.load()` and `.on("load"...` both work in jQ 2.1.4, but I'm using the `.on()` version now

Comment: I use this one plugin.. works perfect https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're concerned about the load method being deprecated, you could get away with using its synonymous form: `$(window).on( "load", handler )`

The load event fires when all images have been loaded.